# cast xmlstring to xml with prefix

Tags: xml, t-sql, xml-parsing

I have a textfield with a product item, a string containing xml, for a product field. I want it parsed, so I can manipulate it.

Apparently I could just do `SELECT cast(xmlstring AS XML) xmldata FROM products` to get the data as xml,
but the xml has fields with g: prefix

```
<item>
  <title>...</title>
  <description>...</description>
  <g:price>123 DKK</price>
  <g:condition>new</g:condition>
  ...
</item>
```

I get error: `XML parsing: line ..., character 6, undeclared prefix`

I tried `with xmlnamespaces('g' as g) SELECT  cast(c.cachevalue as xml ) ...`
but that changed nothing.

Each item is used as a cached item for an xml-feed, so they are wrapped in a

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>Full productfeed</title>
<link>https://www.example.org/gfeed/productfeedxml.xml</link>
<description>
</description>
<item>..</item>
<item>..</item>
<item>..</item>
<item>..</item>
 and end with
</channel>
</rss>
```

So each item in the database is not complete xml.
How can I add the namespace to the query without changing the xml?

Comment: The error is telling you the problem, the prefix `g` isn't defined in that XML, so the XML is not valid. The problem is the XML, not the SQL. If `item` is your root, then it *should* look like `<item xmlns:g="{namespace}">`

Comment: The items are fractions of xml. not a complete xml. See updated question.

Comment: That string converts fine. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=95b3bc73e9fca36fdf340860e3c16910).

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).